# Change the text view width dynamically based on the text width in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have created and added a text field to a view as below

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, 280, 20);
UITextField *utf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
...
[scrollView addSubview:itemBrand];
```

Suppose the text on text view is abcdefghijklmno and the width is 100.

How can I change the with of the text view to 100 instead of 280 dynamically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the size of your text using this function:

```
CGSize textSize = [inputText sizeWithFont:font 
                               constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                                   lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

inputText being the text you want to ask the size of.

font being the font you are using for the text.

maximumLabelSize being the maximum size your text is allowed to be.

After this you can comform your textfield to this size.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the frame over so you can modify if (doing utf.frame.size.width = something, won't work)

```
CGRect f = utf.frame;
f.size.width = yourNewWidth;
utf.frame = f;
```